# Incrementing an image using p5.js - canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Completely stumped over this simple logic. How can I move an image across the screen like a an ellipse/circle?

```
 var storm;

function preload() {
storm = loadImage("250px-Stormtrooper-75060.png");  
}

function setup() {
 background(0);
 createCanvas(1000,600); 
}

function draw() {

image(storm,200,200);
image(storm).x = image(storm).x + 1;
}
```

The draw function loops over.
The error message for this code:

19: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `draw` function to this ...

```
var x = 200, y = 200;
function draw() {
  image(storm, x, y);
  x++;
}
```

Comment: @BenjaminGibbs710 you're welcome :) and it didn't work bcoz, `image` is a literal function, not an object hence, it doesn't have any property called `x`